# How can i trigger my iphone application to launch from my mac app

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, usb, wifi

I want to launch my app on the device (if App available) using the USB\Wifi\Bluetooth connection from my mac app.

How can I achieve this functionality

Answer (score 5):

That is **NOT** possible. You can't do it using any public API. Though i am not aware of any private API that facilitate this types of functionality.

Comment: I'm hoping there should be a way as we can open iOS app with URL scheme from other iOS App.

Comment: Opening iOS app with URL scheme from other iOS App, And opening from a MAC app are completely different thing. No way to mix one with other. Though i am also interested to see if there is any solution.

Comment: It is actually possible using `idevicedebug`, but the phone needs to be used for development, and the app needs to be debuggable.

Answer (score 1):

This is iPad control Mac's touch bar demo:

- [TouchBarDemoApp](https://github.com/bikkelbroeders/TouchBarDemoApp) Allows you to use your macOS Touch Bar from an iPad (through USB connection) or on-screen by pressing the Fn-key.

Mac control iPhone:

- iTunes Mac app can get the iPhone's screenshot and edit iPhone's apps.
- Xcode can launch iPhone's apps when you debug `ShareExtension`.

So I think there are some methods to achieve your function. But I don't how to achieve. Maybe its private.

Answer (score 1):

As already posted, you cannot directly launch an app.

But you can make your App show up on the lock screen as well as the task switcher so it can be opened with one click. This feature is called **Handoff**.

[Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681#handoff) is the usage description for the end user and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/HandoffFundamentals/HandoffFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338) is the programming guide on how to implement it.